# Why does Xcode stop giving text prediction?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to learn how to create apps using Xcode. I usually follow tutorials on the internet as Objective-C and Swift come with built-in methods and functions usually hard to remember (at least for me at this stage). Throughout a project, I do not get predictive text any longer and have to type the whole method word-by-word which is not that bad, but can take more time though.

I wonder if anyone knows how to stop this behaviour. I've searched some topics and found I have to Clean my project and Restart Xcode. I tried that (which is usually more time wasting than typing the code altogether) but it still didn't work. On the same project, the predictive text seems to have ceased.

If I open another project however, it works.

Just to clarify, by predictive text I mean typing "UIView" and getting a dropdown menu with everything I would have typed like "UIViewController".

Thanks for all the anticipated help.

Comment: Are you seeing a message reporting a crash in something called SourceKit? It's also possible you've changed your settings in preferences, to disable suggestions while typing. The default behaviour is to show completions when you press the `esc` key, does that do anything?

Comment: Thank you. I tried the Esc key and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's called ***Code Completion*** (so you can get more results online).

Can be activated in preferences:  "⌘ ," on the **Text Editing** tab

Alternatively, can be called by pressing the keyboard shortcut "⌥ esc".

[image: screenshot code completion]

Comment: I was thinking it may have not been correct how I was searching. Thank you for the info. All the boxes are ticked like in your screenshot. I will search for why does it stop. So far the Esc key works perfectly. Thank you again.