# Xcode 6.1 running on Mavericks Code Completion is broken

Tags: ios, xcode6, code-completion

I have tried deleting my derived data and restarting Xcode, and it works for a few seconds, until the Indexing is complete and then it's broken again.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to fix this?

I searched in the apple developer forums and there are a lot of other users having the same issue. They say to go back to a previous version of Xcode 6 but I don't know where to find one, so any advice on that would be much appreciated as well.

I never realized how much I rely on Code Completion, I am pretty much stuck until I get this fixed.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: [Have a look at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26566164/1672895).

Comment: For older builds: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by upgrading to Xcode6.1.1